# Embedded Video keeps playing even after closed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a video which would keep playing even after I close it.
I feel there is something I am missing in my jQuery.
Could anyone please help me.
Below is the code related to it.

Jquery

```
$("[data-media]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var videoUrl = $this.attr("data-media");
    var popup = $this.attr("href");
    var $popupIframe = $(popup).find("iframe");

    $popupIframe.attr("src", videoUrl);



    var left = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var left = left/2 - 340;

    var top = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    var top = top/2 - 180

    document.getElementById("vid").style.top = top + "px";
    document.getElementById("vid").style.left = left + "px"; 

    $this.closest(".page").addClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(".page").removeClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup > iframe").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="page"> <!-- class "page" is required for video to work-->
        <div class="popup" id="media-popup"> <!-- video embedded -->
            <iframe id="vid" src="http://testvideo.com" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div><!-- popup -->
</div>
```

Comment: And how are you closing it?

Comment: Hi there, I am closing it by clicking anywhere outside the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of video url when you click one, a popup comes up showing the corresponding video.When you are done with that video you want to remove it by clicking outside the iframe but inside popup.

Here is the problem
You are using this `$(".page").removeClass("show-popup");`
to get the second part done removing this class will simply hide it using css `display` or`visibility` it's like making something invisible but still you can hear it, so video is invisible but it's still there playing .To fix this you need to wipe the src of iframe

```
$('.page iframe').attr("src", '');
```

Comment: Awesome I tried this prior to it but didnt remove the $(".page").removeClass("show-popup");

To close the video I removed :
$(".page").removeClass("show-popup");

and added your code
$('.page iframe').attr("src", '');

It worked. Thank you for making me understand it.

Comment: Hi @Novice now that we have done this the video does stop, but if I re-open the same video. The popup is empty. Earlier I didn't have this problem, do you think we need add a showpopup again after this occurs. And if so could you help

Comment: Please check this line `var popup = $this.attr("href");` and   var `$popupIframe = $(popup).find("iframe");` isn't popup a string ? but you are using it like DOM

Comment: Yup nothing really helps.